# NLP textEmbed function

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda, r-text

*I am trying to run the textEmbed function in R.
Set up needed:*

```
  require(quanteda)
  require(quanteda.textstats)
  require(udpipe)
  require(reticulate)


#udpipe_download_model(language = "english")

  ud_eng <- udpipe_load_model(here::here('english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe'))

  virtualenv_list()

  reticulate::import('torch')
  reticulate::import('numpy')
  reticulate::import('transformers')
  reticulate::import('nltk')
  reticulate::import('tokenizers')
  require(text)
```

*It runs the following code*

```
tmp1 <- textEmbed(x = 'sofa help',
                  model = 'roberta-base',
                  layers = 11)

tmp1$x
```

However, it does not run the following code

```
tmp1 <- textEmbed(x = 'sofa help',
                      model = 'roberta-base',
                      layers = 11)
    
    tmp1$x
```

*It gives me the following error*

```
Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `words`.
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this error has been fixed with a newer version of the `text`-package (version .9.50 and above).

(I cannot see any difference in the two code parts – but I think that this error is related to only submitting one token/word to textEmbed, which now works).

Also, see updated instructions for how to install the `text`-package http://r-text.org/articles/Extended_Installation_Guide.html

```
library(text)
library(reticulate)

# Install text required python packages in a conda environment (with defaults).
text::textrpp_install()

# Show available conda environments.
reticulate::conda_list()

# Initialize the installed conda environment.
# save_profile = TRUE saves the settings so that you don't have to run textrpp_initialize() after restarting R. 
text::textrpp_initialize(save_profile = TRUE)

# Test so that the text package work.
textEmbed("hello")
```